# How to update a field at the history table just if it changed ? using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have business table with many fields (col),
field1 , field2 , field3 ...

I want to track the changes at the business table, and save them at the history_table.

I think I can implement that with trigger ? but my problem I don't know how to implement trigger that will write to the history table just the fields that had been changed.

so for example :

```
if (NEW.field1 != OLD.filed1 and NEW.field3 != OLD.field3)
```

as

```
insert INTO history (field1,field3) VALUES (OLD.field1,OLD.field3)
```

notice I don't inset field2 !

Comment: What value should go to those fields that didn't change? Null? What if the new value is Null?

Comment: How many columns are there in business table ?

Comment: @vhu the default values, will go to those field that didn't change !

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty 30 col.

Comment: hmm I see one option to declare 30 variables inside the trigger and defaulting them to NULL and finally check for each kind `NEW.field1 != OLD.filed1` and set the corresponding variable to the new value and finally one insert query with the declared variables.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty could you please give me the sql query for just tow fields ! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can try

```
delimiter //
create trigger history_update after insert on business
for each row
begin
    declare field_1 varchar(200) default NULL ; 
    declare field_2 varchar(200) default NULL ;
    declare field_3 varchar(200) default NULL ;
    declare field_4 varchar(200) default NULL ;
    declare field_5 varchar(200) default NULL ;
    ....
    declare field_30 varchar(200) default NULL ;

    if(NEW.field1 != OLD.filed1) then
        set field_1 = OLD.field1 ;
    end if ;

    if(NEW.field2 != OLD.filed2) then
        set field_2 = OLD.field2 ;
    end if ;
    ...............
    ...............
    if(NEW.field30 != OLD.filed30) then
        set field_30 = OLD.field30 ;
    end if ;

    insert into history 
    (field1,field2,field3.......field30) 
    values
    (field_1,field_2,field_3......field_30);
end ; //

delimiter ;
```